# Echo ACF media attachment custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF gallery named `documentation` and also have set up a radio button custom field named `image_size` on the media attachments, so I can select from various image formats.

I would like to echo the selected `image_size` so I can use it as a class, however I cannot get it to show up.

Below is what I have put together based on the documentation, could someone please help point out where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

```
<?php 
$images = get_field('documentation', $post->ID);
if( $images ): ?>

        <?php
        $documentation_class = get_field('image_size', $images['id']);
        ?>                   
         
        <figure class="<?php echo $documentation_class; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $images[0]["sizes"]["large"]; ?>" />
        </figure>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `$images` is an array of images so `$images['id']` is null. you should use `$images[0]['id']` instead.

Comment: thats it, merci!